# Adding click event to markup I can't edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am not able to edit any of the following markup and I am trying to add a click event to the .datepick-days-cell element.

```
<td class="datepick-days-cell onclick="jQuery.datepick._selectDay(this,'#calendar_booking5',1493179200000)" ></td>
```

I tried the following simple jQuery on click event but had no luck:

```
$('.datepick-days-cell').on('click', function() {
   alert('test click');
});
```

I'm assuming this does not work because it can't take precedence over the event handler that is bound to the element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.datepick-days-cell').on('click',function() {
    alert('test click');
});
});
</script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="datepick-days-cell"  onclick="jQuery.datepick._selectDay(this,'#calendar_booking5',1493179200000)" >Test Click</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$('.datepick-days-cell').click(function() {
      alert('test click');
    });
```